# Regular expression matching in queryDSL

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to do a query in order to reproduce the following in SQL:

```
where REGEXP_LIKE(variable, regular_expression);
```

I tried to use the match predicate and the MATCH operator but it seems that in both cases, the expression is converted to a like by 
[com.mysema.query.types.ExpressionUtils#regexToLike](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.3.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/ExpressionUtils.html#regexToLike%28com.mysema.query.types.Expression%29).

The regexToLike method would reject any '*' or '[' corresponding to a regex syntax and  would throw a QueryException :

> '12-*34' can't be converted to like form"

Is there any way to do this on QueryDSL ?

EDIT : 
The databse is Oracle 11G

The querydsl library used is : *com.mysema.querydsl* version *3.6.9*

I shall try again after migrating to *com.querydsl* 's latest version (4) as sson as spring data 1.12 is released (querydsl 4 support).

Here is the relevant code :

```
String telRegex = "";
            if (this.tel.length() > 1)
            {
                char[] chars = this.tel.toCharArray();
                telRegex += chars[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++)
                {
                    // NB can't make regex to work as special characters are banned cf. ExpressionUtils.regexToLike
                    //telRegex += "-*" + chars[i];
                    telRegex += "" + chars[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                telRegex = rechercheDto.getTelephone();
            }

            telRegex = "^" + telRegex + "$";

            // query
            predicate.and($(contact.getTel()).isNotNull())
            .and(
                $(contact.getTel()).matches(telRegex )
            );
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: Is it a String you're matching? I've tried calling `StringExpression's` `public BooleanExpression matches(String regex)` using Oracle 11G and the SQL to manifest is `regexp_like`. The code looks like `where(tableName.columnThatsAString.matches("^foo$"))`

Comment: If that doesn't help, can we get the version of querydsl you're using and the code please?

Comment: @RobertBain added vesion used in edits. I tried a query just like yours and got  : com.mysema.query.QueryException: '^0493$' can't be converted to like form

Comment: When I asked about the database earlier, it never dawned on me, this is `querydsl-collections`, right? For some reason I assumed it was `querydsl-sql`. If you confirm what project you're using, I'll raise and issue and look into it this weekend.

Comment: @RobertBain i'm using here specifically querydsl-jpa. Sorry should have mentionned it

Comment: I've raised https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1713 and will look into this.

Comment: Thx for the update !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to do a WHERE clause using a REXGEP expression, I use the following code

```
jpaQuery 
  = jpaQuery
      .where
        (Expressions.booleanTemplate
          ("function('REGEXP_LIKE',{0},{1}"
          ,qTable.ctcTireLineName
          ,sRegex
          )
        );
```

I use QueryDSL 3.7.2.

I have just tried using sRegex = "^(EA|SPORT).*" and it work fine in Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching in JPA queries is done with `LIKE` and is limited only to `%` and `_`. Query DSL will try to convert your regular expression into a `LIKE` expression.

From documentation on `StringExpression.matches(String)`

> Some implementations such as Querydsl JPA will try to convert a regex expression into like form and will throw an Exception when this fails

Comment: For me solution was to do an approximate `LIKE` and then filter results in java with `String.matches(String)`

Comment: You are right, thanks. However for a workaround, see schlebe's comment (7/04) https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1713